# Storing spark double values into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a double value (9999999999999.99) and trying to store the same into elastic search document (type double and tried scaled_float as well). But, on the Elasticsearch document the same value being shown as 9.99999999999999E12.
Could some one please educate me to resolve this issue

Comment: According to [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-returned-for-long-numbers-with-elasticsearch-api/19772/3) numbers greater 10^7 are converted to scientific format... I am not sure if this is an issue? Can't you just format the numbers in your application, perhaps when you want to display them? Otherwise what difference does it make?

Comment: You can always store the number as a string in the source document but set the mapping of that field to double

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't actually have a problem, let me explain:

`9999999999999.99` is a normal representation of a floating point value (float, double etc.)
`9.99999999999999E12` is another representation of the same value. `E` meaning Exponent.
Exponent is the same as multiplying by 10 to the power of the exponent value, in this case 12 so 10**12 == 1000000000000.
9.99999999999999 * 1000000000000 == 9999999999999.99

Further explanation:
If you move the decimal point twelve digits to the right, you'll get the same number `9999999999999.99`, and that's what the exponent is used for.
Also the exponent can be negative, in which case you'd move the decimal point to the left.